# Calling a C # method in the server to render an attribute of a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:texbox control like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="wName" runat="server" Text="" MyAttribute='<%# Encrypt("hello") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

I need to call the Encrypt method that it is in a server class (static and public) and that call will return a string like "Yes"
So finally the textbox control should be rendered like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="wName" runat="server" Text="" MyAttribute='Yes' ></asp:TextBox>
```

But when I do it, Encrypt is never called and the control is rendered without MyAttribute, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="wName" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I have done this kind of call in the past inside a gridview for the rendering in one of the columns and it works perfect but here with the textbox is not working.

How can I make it work? I need the value of MyAttribute to be specified dynamically when the screen is "painted", and I can't do it in one of the events (Page_Load, etc.), it needs to be visible the 'hello' in the aspx and the 'Yes' in the page rendered.

Comment: I meant Calling C# method in the server to render and attribute in a textbox

Comment: You should probably edit that title then, lol

Comment: How are you calling the server method?

Comment: This is the call: '<%# Encrypt("hello") %>'

Comment: `<asp:TextBox />` is a server-side control which renders an `<input type=TextBox />` html element.  Since `MyAttribute` is not an attribute of asp:Texbox, you will not be able to add it. There are ways of doing it, but it gets complicated. Would you be willing to consider a different approach, like maybe a js var value or maybe a `hidden` field?

Comment: Thanks tgolish, but ASP respects any attribute you add it and when it finally renders as an html <input> control simply copy whatever you add to it I usually do it. The problem I am asking here is different I need to make a call to a method to get the value of teh attribute